# How to run a remote script with sudo via ssh without entering password

Tags: ssh, scripting, sudo, mkdir

I would like my script to connect to ssh with password, and once connected it will switch to `sudo -s` and run the `mkdir` command

for the moment I manage to connect to ssh without entering the password but I cannot do it user switch to create my folder

Look's like:

```
root@computer:/home/user/test# sshpass -p 'password' ssh admin@192.168.2.250  mkdir /var/volatile/flash-upgrade

mkdir: can't create directory '/var/volatile/flash-upgrade': Permission denied
```

only root user can create folder

Comment: 1) `sudo` command is missing after `ssh` 2) is it always  same host and `mkdir' (with random dir ? random hosts ? ramdom users (not always admin) ?

Comment: Can you ssh as the user who has the permission to write the command? Can you set up the remote host to allow `admin` to run `sudo mkdir /var/volatile/flash-upgrade` without a password (do you own the remote system and can you edit its `/etc/sudoers` file)? How important is security? Is having plaintext passwords in the shell's history a problem or are you the only user of the system?

Answer (score 0):

Either your `admin` user on 192.168.2.250 needs to be able to `sudo` to the correct user, for example `ssh sudo id` or you could set-up ssh-ing to a user that is allowed root access to the machine, so `ssh root@192.168.2.250`.

If you're alone on your home network, both should be OK; in a corporate environment, you should look at the security implications.

Answer (score 0):

you can allow root access only with tagged ssh public key aithentication : in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, set `PermitRootLogin forced-command-only`
Force-command is a command you tag public key in /root/.ssh/authorized_keys such as
`command="script_you_have_strictly_controlled" id-rsa <public key here>`
This way you have a controlled elevation to do only authorized and predefined tasks